# Algorithm to determine the percentage of how matched 2 comibnations are

Tags: algorithm, match, combinations

I have a database that is like this:

```
Set (ID, details)
Set_Member (ID, Member_ID, Value) // multi-valued
```

So they will look like this:

```
Set ID: 1
Details: random letters 1
Members: A, V, F, G, T

Set ID: 2
Details: random letters 2
Members: R, T, B, S, L
```

I have an input of a combination, like (A, T, F) and I want the output to be how strongly matched is the input to the set, like this:

```
Set ID: 1
Match Percentage: 100%

Set ID: 2
Match Percentage: 50%
```

Of course I just made up the example above. I want an algorithm (much better if it is a named algorithm) that will compute the match percentage, and will consider unique entries within sets. Can you suggest some?

*Note: I am using combinations, not permutations.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do you define "Match percentage"? like, Your set members are {A,V,F,G,T}, and your combination is (A,T,F), it's 100 % as it's a subset of the set? Then how to get 50% for example 2?

Comment: ah sorry I just made this up... I am actually using this for a symptom-disease matching... like when the user inputs a symptom that is unique only to a disease, then that disease' match percentage with the input symptom will be 100%, since it is the only possible match.

Comment: Did you take a look at that? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index

Comment: Jaccard can only measure similarities if there are definite variables between 2 entities, like, if they both have length and width... I need something to use with a single multi-valued variable.

Comment: I imagine the first step would be to ensure that any comma-separated lists that you add to the database are alphabetically ordered. The second step would be to reconsider your schema